# Convert case-sensitive HDD to journaled insensitive?

Tags: hard-drive, ssd, file-conversion

Like everyone, I've search everywhere in the web about getting my brother's HDD converted to case-sensitive journaled.

I have a back up HDD that I can transfer to, I have no idea why iPartition is not working with the xnfers. I'm not sure if the HDD is broken. He has all of his information from the HDD like family videos. He does not want to lose it. Hope someone can help with the recovery.

Comment: What does **xnfers** mean?

Comment: Sorry it means Transfer*

Answer (score 1):

Most utilities don't want to deal with the hassle of making sure all the file names work when going from a case sensitive filesystem to a case-insensitive one. For that reason, you'll want to back up, wipe and then restore the files.

You'll want to have a plan for handling a collision when:

- FilEa.DOC
- filea.doc

Happen in the same folder since they can coexist in a case sensitive world but not the other.

Comment: Do you have any programs I can use to do this?

Comment: @jay2x nothing I would use on the only copy of family videos.